# How do I strip a part of URL and set the rest as source using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out on how do I strip a part of URL and set the rest as source using JQuery? (The part of the URL we're trying to get rid of is the actual domain we are on). SO this will be like forcing the internal link to external one by stripping the main domain name and keeping the rest.

Original Code:

```html
<li data-src="http://khan.zaha.in/https://storage.googleapis.com/shahbano-khan/Media/Audio/Desmeon%20-%20Back%20From%20The%20Dead.mp3" data-title="1. Back From the Dead" class="song-row">
```

What i need is:

```html
<li data-src="https://storage.googleapis.com/shahbano-khan/Media/Audio/Desmeon%20-%20Back%20From%20The%20Dead.mp3" data-title="1. Back From the Dead" class="song-row">
```

So we would be getting rid of the originating domain name.

If there is other ways to achieve this, I will be glad to try.
Looking forward to gain healthy help.

Regards,
Syed H

Comment: How are these elements generated, as I'd start there - you could process the 'li' elements (well, elements with 'song-row' class) once page has loaded, but you must be generating them dynamically so you're either doing something wrong there, or you can fix the URL before adding it to the page.

Answer (score 2):

We can strip off unwanted string using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and set it back using `attr(attributeName, value)` methode

```js
var originalStr = $('li').attr('data-src'); // get current src
var strTobeRemvd = 'http://khan.zaha.in/';
var modified = originalStr.replace(strTobeRemvd,''); //remove the unwanted str
$('li').attr('data-src', modified);// set the modified src back

console.log(modified)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-src="http://khan.zaha.in/https://storage.googleapis.com/shahbano-khan/Media/Audio/Desmeon%20-%20Back%20From%20The%20Dead.mp3" data-title="1. Back From the Dead" class="song-row">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all such occurances from any Url and not just from khan.zania domain, this will prove to be more useful as it basically takes the portion of after first http:// or https:// and find the first / till end of url.

```
$('li[data-src^="http"]').each(function(){
    var data=$(this).attr('data-src');
    $(this).attr('data-src',data.slice(data.indexOf('/',8)+1));
});
```

Tried and tested. This works. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're best doing this via regex, then its not domain specific:

```
_src = $('.song-row').data('src');
_src = _src.replace(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?([a-z0-9\-]+)(?:\.[a-z\.]+[\/]?)/g,'');
$('.song-row').attr('data-src', _src);
```

You can see it working here - https://jsfiddle.net/f6f7wwto/2

Comment: I cannot tell you how surprised I am to see responses flowing so fast on StackOverflow. I tried your code and it worked well for changing the source, however the audio does not play and gives me an error in the console. [link]http://khan.zaha.in/index.php/albums/6-miyazaki-naruto would you mind taking a look and help me fix this one.

Comment: It means that the context of the question has changed. In that case can i suggest you mark this answer as correct and open a new question, to which I'd be more than happy to assist you with.